# Select * in sqlAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am struggling to run a select * query in sql alchemy, my table object looks like this,

```
    from sqlalchemy import Column, Date, DateTime, Float, Numeric, Index, Integer, MetaData, SmallInteger, String, UnicodeText, Table, Time, text
from sqlalchemy.types import _Binary

metadata = MetaData()

absence = Table(
    'absence', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('workbase', String(255), index=True),
    Column('name', String(255), nullable=False, index=True),
    Column('submit_date', DateTime, index=True),
    Column('created_1', DateTime, index=True),
    Column('manager_1', String(255), index=True),
    Column('first_day_1', Date, index=True),
    Column('last_day_1', Date, index=True),
    Column('sp_absence_id', Integer, index=True),
    Column('created_2', DateTime, index=True),
    Column('manager_2', String(255), index=True),
    Column('first_day_2', Date, index=True),
    Column('last_day_2', Date, index=True),
    Column('sp_selfcert_id', Integer, index=True),
    Column('sp_selfcert_file', String(255), index=True),
    Column('interview_date', Date, index=True),
    Column('created_3', DateTime, index=True),
    Column('manager_3', String(255), index=True),
    Column('first_day_3', Date, index=True),
    Column('sp_return_id', Integer, index=True),
    Column('sp_return_file', String(255)),
    Column('rostered_days', Float(24), index=True),
    Column('reason', String(255), nullable=False, index=True),
    Column('rtw_trigger', Integer, index=True)
)
```

I have tried countless ways of selecting all

```
absence = tables.absence
#Attempt 1
absence.all()
returns AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'all'
#Attempt 2
absence.query.all()
returns AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'query'
#Attempt 3
sel = select([absence.c.*]).select_from(absence)
absences = FlaskApp.db_connect().execute(sel).fetchall()
returns nothing, but kills my local server.
```

None of the above work, what am I doing wrong I have used ORM previously in other languages and they have always been so simple to get going with,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe you missed the database creation phase described here : http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/metadata.html#creating-and-dropping-database-tables

Try adding (for example using sqlite in RAM):

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Then you can follow instructions described here : http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/tutorial.html#sql-expression-language-tutorial

By the way, the ORM mechanics (wich are not used in you code sample) are well described here : http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use this structure:

## Step 1: Create a meta.py file that is connect to db:

```
# a. Connect to the mydb database:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from settings import info # import info dictionary

engine = create_engine('mysql://{user_name_db}:{password_db}@{host_name_db}:{port_db}/{db_name}?charset=utf8'.format(
    user_name_db=info['user_name_db'],
    password_db=info['password_db'],
    host_name_db=info['host_name_db'],
    port_db=info['port_db'],
    db_name=info['db_name']
), echo=False)

# b. Call the session which bind the db engine to manipulate the database:
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# c. Define the models class mapper:
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
```

## Step 2: Create a tables.py file that is models of your db tables:

```
from sqlalchemy import (Column, Integer, String, DateTime, Date, Float)
from meta import *


class Absence(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'absence'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    workbase = Column(String(255), index=True)
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False, index=True)
    submit_date = Column(DateTime, index=True)
    created_1 = Column(DateTime, index=True)
    manager_1 = Column(String(255), index=True)
    first_day_1 = Column(Date, index=True)
    last_day_1 = Column(Date, index=True)
    sp_absence_id = Column(Integer, index=True)
    created_2 = Column(DateTime, index=True)
    manager_2 = Column(String(255), index=True)
    first_day_2 = Column(Date, index=True)
    last_day_2 = Column(Date, index=True)
    sp_selfcert_id = Column(Integer, index=True)
    sp_selfcert_file = Column(String(255), index=True)
    interview_date = Column(Date, index=True)
    created_3 = Column(DateTime, index=True)
    manager_3 = Column(String(255), index=True)
    first_day_3 = Column(Date, index=True)
    sp_return_id = Column(Integer, index=True)
    sp_return_file = Column(String(255))
    rostered_days = Column(Float(24), index=True)
    reason = Column(String(255), nullable=False, index=True)
    rtw_trigger = Column(Integer, index=True)

    # initialize MyTable_model class
    def __init__(self, id_=None, workbase=None, name=None, submit_date=None, created_1=None, manager_1=None,
                 first_day_1=None, last_day_1=None, sp_absence_id=None, created_2=None, manager_2=None,
                 first_day_2=None, last_day_2=None, sp_selfcert_id=None, sp_selfcert_file=None, interview_date=None,
                 created_3=None, manager_3=None, first_day_3=None, sp_return_id=None, sp_return_file=None,
                 rostered_days=None, reason=None, rtw_trigger=None):
        self.id = id_
        self.workbase = workbase
        self.name = name
        self.submit_date = submit_date
        self.created_1 = created_1
        self.manager_1 = manager_1
        self.first_day_1 = first_day_1
        self.last_day_1 = last_day_1
        self.sp_absence_id = sp_absence_id
        self.created_2 = created_2
        self.manager_2 = manager_2
        self.first_day_2 = first_day_2
        self.last_day_2 = last_day_2
        self.sp_selfcert_id = sp_selfcert_id
        self.sp_selfcert_file = sp_selfcert_file
        self.interview_date = interview_date,
        self.created_3 = created_3
        self.manager_3 = manager_3
        self.first_day_3 = first_day_3
        self.sp_return_id = sp_return_id
        self.sp_return_file = sp_return_file
        self.rostered_days = rostered_days
        self.reason = reason
        self.rtw_trigger = rtw_trigger
```

## Step 3: Create a driver.py file that is your queries :

```
from tables import *


class MyAbsence(Absence):

    # - Add a new record
    def create(self):
        try:
            new_record = Absence(workbase=self.workbase, name=self.name, submit_date=self.submit_date)  # ....
            session.add(new_record)
            session.flush()
            session.refresh(new_record)
            id_record = new_record.id
            session.commit()
            return id_record
        except Exception as e:
            print("ERROR : MyAbsence.create : " + str(e))
            return 0

    @staticmethod
    def get_all():
        try:
            return [{"id": dic.id, "workbase": dic.workbase, "name": dic.name, "submit_date": dic.submit_date}  # ...
                    for dic in session.query(Absence).all()]
        except Exception as e:
            print("ERROR : MyAbsence.get_all : " + str(e))
            return []
```

## Step 4 : Using , for example:

```
object_abs = MyAbsence()
ls = object_abs.get_all()
print(ls)
```